# Access responseBytes of a reusable feature call

Tags: karate

I would like to access the responseBytes of a reusable feature and compare it to a local file.
I have two feature files in this example. The file ***general.feature*** should call ***loadPicture.feature*** and access its responseBytes.
My idea was that I could do the following:

```
general.feature:

* def pictureCall = call read('loadPicture.feature')
Then match pictureCall.responseBytes == read('file.jpeg')
```

However, this fails with the message:

```
path: $.responseBytes, actual: null, expected: java.io.FileInputStream@353f377a, reason: actual json-path does not exist
```

Inside the reusable feature, however, I can do the following without problems

```
loadPicture.feature:

Then match responseBytes == read('file.jpeg')
```

---

Even if I store the responseBytes inside the reusable feature in a variable, it doesn't work as expected:

```
loadPicture.feature:

* def pictureBytes = responseBytes
```

```
general.feature:

* def pictureCall = call read('loadPicture.feature')
Then match pictureCall.pictureBytes == read('file.jpeg')
```

---

The only thing that works is the following:

```
loadPicture.feature:

* bytes pictureBytes = responseBytes
```

```
general.feature:

* def pictureCall = call read('loadPicture.feature')
And bytes image = read('file.jpeg')
Then match image == pictureCall.pictureBytes
```

What confuses me here is that the following again does not work:

```
loadPicture.feature:

* bytes pictureBytes = responseBytes
```

```
general.feature:

* def pictureCall = call read('loadPicture.feature')
Then match pictureCall.pictureBytes == read('file.jpeg')
```

---

Is there an explanation for this? Does it have anything to do with the types of the variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the `responseBytes` is special and internally we don't pass it around as an optimization. As you can imagine this can bloat memory very quickly.

You are welcome to contribute code to improve this or update the documentation.

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain me why I can't initialize the value of responseBytes with def as a variable, but need the byte keyword? According to the documentation, responseByte already is an byte array.

Comment: @elPaso yes this behaves differently. and because it is binary. everything else in karate / json is string-like